# Is there a way to check multiple escape characters with one escape character in C++?

Tags: c++, string, serial-port, escaping, ascii

Man that's an awkwardly formed question.

My project right now is reading from a serial port ASCII lines. I'm using a private library that reads output line by line. Each line is identified as such with the \r character. I'm limited by this library because I have to specify what escape character ends that line.

Anyway, I found [this documentation online](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v8r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.netcool_OMNIbus.doc_7.3.1%2Fomnibus%2Fwip%2Fcommon%2Freference%2Fomn_ref_re_backslashsequences.html) and in particular, I am interested in the escape characters \> and \s because \> checks for the end of a string and \s checks for any whitespace escape characters.

However, I don't think this is available by default in C++. I'm not even sure what language that documentation is for!

So I ask the gurus of stackoverflow; Is there a way to check multiple escape characters in C++ with only one escape character?

Thanks for reading..

Comment: That's not a C++ escape sequence. That documentation is for regular expressions.

Comment: Yes, that's totally unclear.  First, if you know your source produces known characters, why are you interested in detecting others?  Second, I'm not sure what you mean by "check multiple characters with one character"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [std::regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) from the C++11 standard.

If you compiler does not support that, you can also use [QRegularExpression](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qregularexpression.html) if you do not mind using Qt 5.

You could probably also use the [regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) from the boost library for this.

If you wanna go down C in favor of supporting older compilers, you could even use [regex(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/regex).

Comment: Or Posix's `<regex.h>` from the POSIX C library.

Comment: @H2CO3: Good point, I have just added the documentation for that, too!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it definitely is an "awkwardly formed question".

Regarding the second point, you are confusing escape characters with regular expression constructs/escapes.  The second are valid only within regular expressions.  Unless your library supports them, you will not be able to use them successfully.  `C++` does not provide any direct support for regular expressions.  Only through library functions.